# Define a method within a block's scope, while still having access to the global scope in Ruby, without block arguments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, metaprogramming

I want to simplify some tests.  Specifically, I want to define a block assertion method, where inside the block you have access to a special helper method, while still also having access to the test context.  Something like this:

```
def assert_metric(report, metric, &block)
  def sum(value, *filters)
    filters.each do |filter|
      assert_equal value, report.sum(metric, filter)
    end
  end
  instance_eval(&block)
end

assert_metric report, :select_count do
  sum 1
  sum 1, :bookmark, :like
  sum 0, :vote
end
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Constraints*:

- `sum` method is executed in the currently executing test's context (so you could do `assert_equal` and access all instance variables.
- `sum` isn't available outside of that block
- You don't yield a block argument (i.e. `do |test_context|...`)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be assuming that that `def sum` works like a nested function in Python. It doesn't. That will define a method on your test class. There's no way to define a method only within another method — methods belong to classes or objects. You can, however, define an object that only exists there which implements the method.

If I understand your requirements correctly, the closest equivalent would be something like:

```
require 'delegate'

def assert_metric(report, metric, &block)
  ctx = SimpleDelegator.new(self)
  ctx.singleton_class.class_eval do
    define_method(:sum) do
      filters.each {|filter| assert_equal value, report.sum(metric, filter)}
    end
  end
  ctx.instance_eval(&block)
end
```